# MySQL: Use the column's value on the same row for counting

Tags: mysql

How do I use the value from other's column so I can create another column with the sum of all the same type.

e.g.

```
+---------+------+
|  name   | team |
+---------+------+
| Michael | red  |
| Lebron  | blue |
| Ben     | red  |
| Tiger   | red  |
| John    | blue |
+---------+------+
```

Output:

```
+---------+------+----------------+
|  name   | team | member_counter |
+---------+------+----------------+
| Michael | red  |              3 |
| Lebron  | blue |              2 |
| Ben     | red  |              3 |
| Tiger   | red  |              3 |
| John    | blue |              2 |
+---------+------+----------------+
```

As you can see there 3 reds and 2 blues. So is there anyway I can use the value of previous columns? count(team=previous column)? as member_counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a `join` with a sub select of all the teams

```
select name, team, teams.count 
 from names
 join (select team, count(1) as count from names group by team) as teams
using (team);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fab8/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` to a derived table containing `team` counts:

```
SELECT m.name, m.team, t.cnt AS  member_counter
FROM mytable AS m
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT team, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY team ) t
ON m.team = t.team
```

This is likely to perform better than a correlated sub-query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e17e5/1)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you just want the result like this, you can do :

   ```
   SELECT T1.name,T1.team,T2.member_count
   FROM TableName T1 JOIN
     (SELECT name,team,count(team) as member_count
      FROM TableName
      GROUP BY team) T2 ON T1.team=T2.team
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   name    team    member_count
   ----------------------------
   Michael red     3
   Lebron  blue    2
   Ben     red     3
   Tiger   red     3
   John    blue    2
   ```

   Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b521/5).
2. If you are trying to add one more column `member_counter` to your table, you can do this:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE TableName
   ADD member_counter INT NULL


   UPDATE TableName a 
      JOIN 
      (SELECT name,team,COUNT(team) as member_counter
       FROM TableName b
       GROUP BY team) b ON a.name = b.name  AND a.team=b.team
   SET a.member_counter = b.member_counter
   ```

   Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55078/1).

Comment: @Angelo: See the first part in my answer, then.

Answer (score -1):

Just do a subquery:

```
select *, (select count(*) from table t2 where t1.team = t2.team) as member_counter 
from table t1
```

**EDIT:**

I have checked for 1 million rows. Execution plans of this query and query from accepted answer are 99% identical. With time statistics both queries perform absolutely the same. With IO statistics both queries perform absolutely the same. And now I just can't get why I got downvoted. The only difference is my version is shorter and more understandable.

**EDIT2:**

This is working fiddle:

```
select *, (select count(*) from tmp t2 where t1.team = t2.team) as member_counter 
from tmp t1
```

Comment: Apart from being syntactically incorrect this has terrible performance since this will run a DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, once for each row in the table.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand, are you so sure? May be reread some manual? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97d81/1

And second, engine is not so stupid to evaluate same subquery for every row in outer query...

Comment: I am sure. As you know your answer isn't the same as your fiddle, so you've spotted the errors as well... the engine will evaluate the sub query once for each team which in this simple case is "just" twice. With 10 colors it would evaluate 10 times.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand, do you think I am blind? SHOW ME THE SYNTAX ERROR!

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand, so where did I spotted errors and corrected? :) Both queries are the same and working. Engine will not evaluate subquery for every row. It is not correct. In both versions there are 2 scans of table. First to construct the hashtable of dictionary<team, color>. This is where you get distinct teams and counts. Both queries do a table scan for this. Then the second table scan for output and hash join. Just try it out and see both query plans man....

Comment: Your original SQL doesn't work, as I said. Your "edit 2" works, thats fine. Also, try with 1 million rows with 1 million different teams/colors, it will evaluate once for each. You can read about that here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand, see edit history, edit1 and edit2 are the same queries. Why are you lying? I didn't edit the query. As for 1000000 distinct teams, what do you think about your group by? It is the same. No metter. It will build hashtable of million teams in both my and your query. I'm just done here. Your words are just words without proofs and experiment...